# trouble running i2c and spi at the same time

Tags: arduino-uno, i2c, spi, teensy

I know this question has been asked before but I am having trouble running I2c and SPI at the same time. I am attaching my code below. The problem when I run the code is that the LED's don't blink until the OLED function has been complete, can I fix this with hardware? do I need to fix this in the code? (please note I am using a teensy 3.2)

My end goal is to be able to initially turn on the teensy, choose a pattern on the OLED for what led's turn on, and then just have the leds run.

code :

```
#include <SPI.h>
SPISettings settingsA(2000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE1);
#include <SFE_MicroOLED.h>  // Include the SFE_MicroOLED library
#include <Wire.h>  // Include Wire if you're using I2C


int time_interval_for_chip = 1;
int blinking_interval = 500;
unsigned long current_time = 0;
#define PIN_RESET 9  // Connect RST to pin 9

#define DC_JUMPER 0

MicroOLED oled(PIN_RESET, DC_JUMPER);    // I2C declaration

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  SPI.begin();
  SPI.beginTransaction(settingsA);

  oled.begin();    // Initialize the OLED
  oled.clear(ALL); // Clear the display's internal memory
  oled.display();  // Display what's in the buffer (splashscreen)
  delay(1000);     // Delay 1000 ms
  oled.clear(PAGE); // Clear the buffer.

  randomSeed(analogRead(A0) + analogRead(A1));

  //SPISettings object is used to configure the SPI port for your SPI device. All 3 parameters are combined to a single SPISettings object, which is given to SPI.beginTransaction().
  //sending in bits by MSB first and using SPI_MODE1 which is output edge rising data capture falling
  // can be set to either 4000000 or 2000000
}

void loop() {

  //Blinks output 4 and 8 on and off with teensy without spi.endtrasaction()
  //delaying with delay void function made
  unsigned int result = 0;
  unsigned int result2 = 0;
  byte inbyte = 0;
  byte inbyte2 = 0;

  digitalWrite(10, LOW);
  result2 = SPI.transfer16(0b0100000100000100);
  Serial.print("result= ");
  Serial.println(result2, BIN);
  digitalWrite(10, HIGH);

  //getting the time
  current_time = millis();
  delaying(current_time, 1);



  digitalWrite(10, LOW);
  result = SPI.transfer16(0b0000010000010000);
  Serial.print("result2= ");
  Serial.println(result, BIN);
  digitalWrite(10, HIGH);


  //getting the time
  current_time = millis();
  delaying(current_time, 300);


  digitalWrite(10, LOW);
  result2 = SPI.transfer16(0b0100000000000100);
  Serial.print("result1= ");
  Serial.println(result2, BIN);
  digitalWrite(10, HIGH);

  //getting the time
  current_time = millis();
  delaying(current_time, 1);


  digitalWrite(10, LOW);
  result = SPI.transfer16(0b0000000000010000);
  Serial.print("result2= ");
  Serial.println(result, BIN);
  digitalWrite(10, HIGH);


  //getting the time
  current_time = millis();
  delaying(current_time, 100);
  lineExample();  // Run the pixel example function

}






void lineExample()
{
  int middleX = oled.getLCDWidth() / 2;
  int middleY = oled.getLCDHeight() / 2;
  int xEnd, yEnd;
  int lineWidth = min(middleX, middleY);

  printTitle("Lines!", 1);

  for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
  {
    for (int deg=0; deg<360; deg+=15)
    {
      xEnd = lineWidth * cos(deg * PI / 180.0);
      yEnd = lineWidth * sin(deg * PI / 180.0);

      oled.line(middleX, middleY, middleX + xEnd, middleY + yEnd);
      oled.display();
      delay(10);
    }
    for (int deg=0; deg<360; deg+=15)
    {
      xEnd = lineWidth * cos(deg * PI / 180.0);
      yEnd = lineWidth * sin(deg * PI / 180.0);

      oled.line(middleX, middleY, middleX + xEnd, middleY + yEnd, BLACK, NORM);
      oled.display();
       current_time = millis();
  delaying(current_time, 10);
    }
  }
}

void printTitle(String title, int font)
{
  int middleX = oled.getLCDWidth() / 2;
  int middleY = oled.getLCDHeight() / 2;

  oled.clear(PAGE);
  oled.setFontType(font);
  // Try to set the cursor in the middle of the screen
  oled.setCursor(middleX - (oled.getFontWidth() * (title.length() / 2)),
                 middleY - (oled.getFontWidth() / 2));
  // Print the title:
  oled.print(title);
  oled.display();

  //getting the time
  current_time = millis();
  delaying(current_time, 1500);
  oled.clear(PAGE);
}

void delaying(unsigned long current_time, int period) {

  while (millis() < current_time + period) {
    //wait approx. [period] ms
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you replace the use of millis with normal delay and test again? The usage of millis is wrong, your sketch could delay by 50 days sometimes. You say the the blinking on the leds is delayed. How much slower is it? The i2c bus is slow, and all those delays and millis make the sketch even slower. Why do you have so many delays and complain about the delays? I count 1.4 seconds delay in the function lineExample alone.

Comment: can you explain how I am using millis() wrong? that would be constructive

Comment: See the blink without delay example: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay As soon as you compare a value to the return value of millis(), that's wrong. You can use the blink without delay twice to do multiple things at once. Update the SPI at a fast rate and the oled at a slow rate.

Comment: ok I see what you mean for 1 but I don't see how this is wrong. I followed this link https://www.norwegiancreations.com/2017/09/arduino-tutorial-using-millis-instead-of-delay/

Comment: what my code is doing is it won't run the OLED and the led's at the same time, the OLED function needs to be complete before the leds run but I want to run the two at the same time.

Comment: I quickly removed the problem when the parameter is just 1 from my comment. I was not thinking that through. The blink-without-delay shows how to use millis. Do not follow what is written in that norwegian link, it is totally wrong. The blink-without-delay shows how to use millis. Can you try to use the blink-without-delay and have two leds blinking at different rates, completely independent of each other?

Comment: I will change it, but I don't see how what that person did was wrong, it makes sense.

Comment: No, not at all, it is really a bad example. That code is also here: https://dzone.com/articles/tackling-the-new-world-of-iot-management and there are comments there saying it is bad and harmful. You had bad luck finding that. The function millis() will rollover after 50 days, it is simple to avoid problems with the rollover by using it in the way the blink-without-delay shows.

Comment: I genuinely think if I change it to the other it won't make a difference. I use to use the while loop at Johns Hopkins University in their labs, so that doesn't make sense to me that this will (make or break it)

Comment: Use the blink-without-delay, do not compare the millis value directly to an other value. Everyone who knows about millis can tell you that.

Comment: An interupt could come in and be handled between when you record millis and when you wait for it. It might not be accurate.    However if the function is taking a long time to come back you cant do anything else since its blocking.  Unless you rewrite the function to be shorter, or use interrupts to drive your leds

Comment: can I drive the led's with the interrupt? I thought an interrupt was suppose to be for a quit time.  Just to clarify my exact goals, I want to do some things initially on the OLED to control how the LED's behave, like pick a pattern on my OLED and then the LED's do that. maybe there is a better way to do what I want?

Comment: I think you don't need interrupts for this. You just have to write your OLED and LED code non-blocking. The point of the `BlinkWithoutDelay` example is to not do busy waiting (what you are doing with your `delaying` function (doing a delay with your own function using `millis()` doesn't make sense eiter)), but to only do a short check in every loop cycle, if it is time to do something, and else going further in the code.